# My Django app passes authentication on localhost, but not on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

So I created a simple "social media website" where by using API I GET data from a database and I can also POST to create a social media post after I register and log in.
On my localhost it all works well. I can register, login, then write a social media post and it displays on the screen.
However, when I use Heroku, GET API works fine, but after I log in (and I am sure I am logged in as I can log in on admin), I cannot write anything on my website. In my IDE I get: Forbidden: /api/posts/action/

In the network page I can see this:

Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/posts/action/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Any idea where should I look for an error? If there is any code I should send, let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your server's domain in Heroku shouldn't be `localhost:8000`
You need to use the correct domain/IP address, and remember to put the domain/IP address in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the setting file.

If you don't set up a custom domain, then the default domain should be like:

`https://<dyno name>.herokuapps.com`